# mysql outer join (unselected) on assosiative table

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause, outer-join

I have 3 table = 'Test','Test_quo','Subject'

**Table Test**

```
idtest | Test
1      | Test wave 1
2      | Test Wave 2
```

**Table Test_quo**

```
idtest | idsubject
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 1
```

**Table Subject**

```
  idsubject| subject
    1      | Math
    2      | Bio
    3      | Sport
    4      | Literature
```

what I need is to select outer (unselected subject in certain test),
for example on idtest=1 the result will be literature

```
 idsubject | subject
    4      | Literature
```

somehow I already tried using left, outer didn't work what expected instead result (selected/choosen) subject.

```
SELECT subject.idsubject, subject FROM subject right OUTER JOIN test_quo ON (subject.idsubject = test_quo.idsubject) where test_quo.idtest=1'
```

query I have will result

```
idsubject | subject
       1  | Math
       2  | Bio
       3  | Sport
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear on the logic for what you want to do.  Why do you want `idsubejct = 4`?

Comment: i wanna give select which give option of subject never taken on certain test.
for example test already had Math, Bio, Sport. The option given is only Literature (Prevent primary key check as well) because when two pk meets will error isn't it? due to assosiative table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something like below. It will give you "unselected" subjects for all tests.

```
SELECT subject.idsubject, subject 
FROM subject 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_quo ON (subject.idsubject = test_quo.idsubject) 
WHERE ISNULL(test_quo.idsubject)
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9627/4)

Only for `idtest=1` I came up with the following correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT s.idsubject, subject 
FROM subject s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM test_quo t 
                  WHERE s.idsubject = t.idsubject AND t.idtest = 1)
```

[**Another Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9627/7)

And (finally) the same as OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT subject.idsubject, subject 
FROM subject 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_quo ON (subject.idsubject = test_quo.idsubject AND test_quo.idtest = 1)
WHERE ISNULL(test_quo.idsubject)
```

[**Demo with one more subject**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a3c12/1)

Comment: Fixed it. Please try again.

Comment: the problem occur when I change several values on table test_quo, the result always 4 | Litarature

Comment: Please post (add to your question) your data that breaks my code.

Comment: your code, as my assumption will only read (certain subject never taken by all test). what I want is read subject that never been taken by certain test.

Comment: See my 2nd solution.

Comment: Just for completeness posted the same using `OUTER JOIN` notation.

Comment: have been researching about outer join but no result so ask here. but thanks anw for your help